# Writing event based async methods to return a value to the caller

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, .net-4.5, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to work with silverlight generate WCF methods (SLSVCUTIL).  I have a WCF service that returns a string.  However, I have to use async methods which have a GetStringValueAsync and GetStringValueCompleted.  But my caller is expecting a string return value.  How do I wire up this patter so the caller can call the method and it can return a string?

Let's say I have a button and when it's tapped it will present a message to the user which is the local time of the server.  The message is retrieved from the WCF service via GetServerTimeAsync().

```
void ShowServerTime_ButtonClick()
{
   string result = MyServiceHandler.GetServerTime();
}

public class MyServiceHandler
{
   public static string GetServerTime()
   {
       //method to call is WCFService.GetServerTimeAsync()
       //how do I write this so I can return a string value to the caller?
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want to set up an Action delegate, so that you can write `MyServiceHandler.GetServerTime(result => ...)`.  I like setting it up like this:

```
void ShowServerTime_ButtonClick()
{
    MyServiceHandler.GetServerTime(result => {
        // do something with "result" here
    });
}

public class MyServiceHandler
{
    // wire up the handler in the constructor
    static MyServiceHandler()
    {
        WCFService.GetServerTimeCompleted += (sender, args) 
        {
            // assume you're going to pass the callback delegate in the User State:
            var handler = args.UserState as Action<string>;
            if (handler != null) handler(args.Result);
        }
    }

    public static string GetServerTime(Action<string> callback)
    {
        // send the callback so that the async handler knows what to do:
        WCFService.GetServerTimeAsync(callback)
    }
}
```

Of course, since you're working with .NET 4.5 / Silverlight 5, you could delve into the [async/await stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx), which is nice syntactic sugar (if you're into that kind of thing).

Comment: Thanks, I can't use async await or task based service generation as I'm programming in Xamarin iOS which doesn't support it I don't think.